# Alert if a process has uploaded more than X bytes over the last Y seconds

Tags: windows, security, network-monitor, internet, firewall

I am looking for a Windows program that can give a process has uploaded more than X bytes over the last Y seconds. E.g., if the running Oracle server has uploaded more than 1 GB over the last hour,  it should give an alert. Gratis is better. Ideally, it could allow to whitelist IP (i.e., IPs for which uploading to doesn't count).

Answer (score 2):

[NetWorx](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) (gratis) can do this. In the Notifications settings you can set X data within Y time:

[image: Notification Settings]